# how do I solve a 404 error from a pretty url?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to redirect my content removing the .php extension from all the files using this .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

and when I try to include any other redirect like this one give me a 404 error:

```
RewriteRule ^create/(.*)$ ./create.php?app=$1
```

I'm trying to use something like https://myurl.com/create/37744e17-98ff-58a9-8996-7cf746e508b9 instead of https://myurl.com/create.php?id=37744e17-98ff-58a9-8996-7cf746e508b9, but looks like the start of my .htaccess it's giving the main issue, there's a way to solve this?

Comment: Could you please do let know where is your .htaccess file is placed? And where is your .php files are present? Thank you.

Comment: both are on subdomain folder https://admin.example.com/ so it's almost like https://example.com/admin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've not stated *where* you are putting that rule. It would need to go first. The order is important.

Try it like this instead:

```
# Disable MultiViews
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^create/([a-f0-9-]+)$ create.php?id=$1 [L]

# General extensionless ".php" URLs
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

Note that you used an `id` URL parameter in your example, but used `app` in your rule? I've changed this to `id`.

Based on your example URL, the `id` URL parameter can consist of the characters a-z, 0-9 and hyphens only.

The `RewriteBase` directive is not required. The `./` prefix on the substitution string is not required and should be removed.

In your original rule that appends the file extension there is no need to check that the request does not map to a directory before checking that it does map to a file (with a `.php` extension). You were also potentially checking a different file-path to the one being rewritten to.

Note that you need to ensure that MultiViews is disabled, otherwise `create.php` is called but without the URL parameter.